# Android GridView hours and events

Tags: android, gridview

In my `GridView` I want to have two columns. In the first I want to display an array of times, in the second column I want to display some strings that correspond to the times in the first column. How can I implement this?

This is what I have so far:

```
//hours array
static final String[] orari = new String[] {
        "8:00", "8:30", "9:00", "9:30", "10:00",
        "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00", "12:30",
        "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30", "15:00",
        "15:30", "16:00", "16:30", "17:00", "17:30",
        "18:00", "18:30", "19:00", "19:30", "20:00"
};

String event1; //8:30
String evenet2; //12:30

private GridView gridView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elenco_appuntamenti, container, false);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, orari);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: You can do this by implementing it that way. Do you have a specific question or do you just want someone here to do your work for you? Because nobody is going to do that.

Comment: I do not want someone to do it for me, but tell me what is the right way to do it.

Comment: There are a million ways to do this and there is most definitely no right way. Questions like that are off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: And just for the record: Why do you need a `GridView` in the first place? Why aren't you just using a simple `ListView` or `RecyclerView` and display the time and the corresponding String in the same row? I see no reason to have either a `GridView` or multiple columns.

Comment: I thought of a `GridView `because if I want to add more events for the same time, I need to create columns dynamically.

Comment: Well a `GridView` is not built for that. A `GridView` is made to arrange `Views` dynamically across the screen based on how much space there is. Look at Google Keep or Google+. The cards are `Views` in a `GridView` (actually a `RecyclerView`) and based on how much space there is you have a different amount of `Views` in the same row. You should just use a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`.

Comment: You are better off overriding an array adapter and inserting rows into a ListView or RecyclerView.  Each row in the list would have two views side-by-side so it will look like a grid but not restricted so you can be more dynamic with the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just want two columns so you can set this either in your layout file:

```
<GridView
 ...
 android:numColumns="2"/>
```

Or in code:

```
gridView.setNumColumns(2);
```

Now everything you put into the array that populates the grid will be placed into the correct position.

arrayElement1, arrayElement2, arrayElement3, arrayElement4...  will display like this:

```
1,2
3,4
...
```

If it must be dynamic then I don't think that the `GridView` with a passed in list of static objects is the best way to go.  I would use a `ListView` and override an adapter that allows you to populate a custom view that has two `FrameLayout` views next to each other inside another `LinearLayout` - the left frame with the time and right frame with the string you want to display next to it.  This method will give you the same appearance of the grid view with two columns but give you far more control over everything about the process.

**elenco_appuntamenti.xml** (your layout file)

```
...
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/container"
  ....
  />
...
```

**individual_row.xml** This will be the row that contains both the time and the event text next to each other.  This is each row that we will push into the `ListView`.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8:00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/timeText"/>

    </FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EVENT"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/eventText"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Adapter to populate the rows with data:

```
public class yourAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    public class EntryHolderItem{

        TextView txtTime;
        TextView txtEvent;

    }

    List<SettingsMenuEntry> itemList;
    EntryHolderItem viewHolder;
    public SomeObject entry_object;

    public yourAdapter(Context _context, int layout, List<SettingsMenuEntry> itemList){
        super(_context, layout, itemList);

        this.itemList = itemList;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        if(convertView == null){


            String inflator = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;

            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflator);

            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.individual_row, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new EntryHolderItem();
            viewHolder.txtTime    = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
            viewHolder.txtEvent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventText);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }else{

            viewHolder = (EntryHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
        }

        entry_object = getItem(position);

        //if you pass in just your list of times that you have built already you will only have
        //a string object available to you
        viewHolder.txtTime.setText(entry_object);
        viewHolder.txtEvent.setText("event goes here");

        //but if you decide to create a list of objects that have fields you could do something
        //like this:
        //obviously this will break if you are not passing in an object with 
        //these fields
        //viewHolder.txtTime.setText(entry_object.time);
        //viewHolder.txtEvent.setText(entry_object.event);

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Now you can call yourAdapter much like you already have and setting the adapter on your listView.  You will want to replace your GridView with a ListView in your `elenco_appuntamenti` layout:

```
listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.container);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new yourAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, orari);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: No, I must insert the strings dynamically. What is the right way?

Comment: hav you seen my answer ? :)

Comment: I updated my answer with the approach that I would personally use for this scenario.

Comment: @Shifar Shifz your answer is not seen

Comment: It seems that all have the same idea. Can I find an example in the network?

Comment: Ok I updated my answer.  I haven't tested any of this but it's the basic idea of using an adapter to populate views.

Comment: No problem.  If you need more help then update your question with the code you have written to implement this and we can continue from that point.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to create a Model Class with gets() sets(), and also want to create a Custom BaseAdapter. So it will be so easy to handle.

If you don't know how to do, tell me, i will make it clear.